# how to hide keyboard immediately after tapping on a text field?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have a custom textfield. It opens a pop-up using `UITableViewController`, when user taps on it.

**I wanted to prevent keyboard to pop-up for my text field, looks like it is not possible.**

So I tried the following code which works in simulator, but **it does not work for an actual iPhone!!!**

```
    @IBAction func provincePressed(_ sender: Any) {
         (sender as AnyObject).resignFirstResponder()
         self.view.endEditing(true)
```

What is wrong? and how can I make it work for an actual iPhone? or possibly prevent keyboard to show up at all!

Comment: So what's the purpose of tapping a textfield without displaying the keyboard? What are you aiming to achieve? if there is an irrelevant functionality, you could use a button instead...

Comment: He is opening some kind of menu to select, i think so?

Comment: @AhmadF Its neither a text field nor a button - in nature. I have subclassed `UITextField` to create a custom widget for what I am about to do. I want the keyboard to be active in case the internet connection is not available,However I do not need a keyboard while there is an internet connection. there is some logic behind using textfield, believe me.

Comment: @HarjotSingh Yes, Thats what I am doing and I want to write the selected item in my text field.

Comment: Ok then put a button over the text field and show menu no need to add extra code for the textfield.Putting button over textfield makes all the four answers below useless.

Comment: @HarjotSingh I need to provide a keyboard in special circumstances. It needs to be a TextField.

Comment: @Zich then i am adding an answer read check and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return false in the textFieldShouldBeginEditing method

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the text field’s `isEnabled` to `false` beforehand.

Comment: "I have a custom textfield. It opens a pop-up using UITableViewController, when user taps on it." Don't you think that setting `isEnabled` to `false` would prevent what mentioned (the "tapping")? If I'm not mistaking, I think that it should be even a button instead of textfield for this case...

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

You can just call `textField.resignFirstResponder()` inside `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method like this :

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
    if (textField.tag == 1) {
        //this is textfield 2, so call your method here
       textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

You should give the wanted textfield a tag. If you want the same behavior for all textfields in your **ViewContriler** then that part is not needed.

Also, don't forget to extend your ViewController from `UITextFieldDelegate` and delegate the textField to your ViewController .

`textField.delegate = self`

Comment: I did, it works in simulator but not in an actual iPhone

Comment: maybe it should be called every time the user edit in text , so try to call textField.resignFirstResponder() inside textFieldDidChange

Answer (score 0):

This is according to the SafoineMoncefAmine Answer.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
    if (textField == yourTextfield) {// No need tag Use QA Manager to handle the textfield

       textField.resignFirstResponder()
       // Open your menu here, add view, show the menu here.

    }
}
```

In addition to this answer,

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField,
                   shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange,
                   replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == YourTextField{
        return false
        }
        else{
        return true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable user interaction from `UITextField` , and cover it with `UIView` and add `uigesturerecognizer` to that view to trigger your event .